# Xquery to move xml docs to filesystem in ML?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Can we facilitate a code to move documents from ML db to filesystem ? What API I can use to achieve that ? The documents are in XML format and I want to move it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

This is called 'exporting'.  Look for [MLCP](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/mlcp) as the main supported application to do this: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/export

You can also do it from within MarkLogic by using  [`xdmp:save()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:save)

And from 'outside', all of the API's support this as well.

"Exporting" is the same as "Query" + "Save"   -- so any API that allows you to get a document, such as the REST API document endpoint, is 1 step from saving that to a file (your code).
The default for most of these API's is documents are exported 'as is' - i.e. if its an XML document in the DB it will export as XML,  JSON as JSON etc.

<bias>There is also ml:get from xmlsh  http://www.xmlsh.org/MarkLogicGet </bias>